# Deleting .rbenv from Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rbenv

How can i completely **uninstall** `rbenv` ?

I want to install `rvm` and I want to get rid of `rbenv` completely so they don't clash.

This is what I did so far:

1. `rm -rf ~/.rbenv`
2. cleared all the lines added to my `~/.profile` file
3. closed and reopened my shell

But still get left with a `rbenv` command line tool so when i run `rbenv` i get the same output as before, with all the options, minus all the ruby versions i had installed before.

**EDIT:**

When i run `which rbenv` i get `usr/bin/rbenv`. Should it be safe to just delete it from there?

Comment: Try closing and reopening your shell. Is it still there?

Comment: yes, i tried that already

Comment: How did you install it?  If you used a package manager, e.g. `apt-get` I would try using that, e.g. `apt-get remove rbenv`

Comment: Actually i didn't use a package manager, i followed the instructions here: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#installation

And this did the trick. Write your explanation as an answer so i can accept it, or even rather, i would erase this question cause it is too embarrassing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Michael Durrant helped me with his comment, i was an idiot not to think that way in the first place, i just had to do:

> apt-get remove rbenv

Since i didn't install it through a package manager, rather followed the instructions on GitHub, i thought that it wasn't appropriate (although i first tried `apt-get uninstall` instead of `apt-get remove`).

Comment: 'apt-get remove' didn't do anything for me.  I executed the commands that @zippie listed in the original post and also removed rbenv stuff from .bashrc.  After that, rbenv appeared to be gone.

Comment: I had to do the same, rbenv wasn't installing the ruby versions `2.1.0` and `2.2.0` strange. I used RVM and wanted to try `rbenv`

Comment: I use `apt-get autoremove rbenv` that works fine for me.

Comment: It didn't work for me, I run the command you mentioned and removed `rbenv` from my system but when I check it using a command `rbenv -v` it shows me the version of `rbenv`.

Answer (score 3):

If you installed rbenv using apt-get, then

```sh
apt-get remove rbenv
```

or

```sh
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove rbenv
```

is a good first step. Next steps should be: nuke the `~/.rbenv` directory and all references to "rbenv" in `~/.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, or similar shell initialization files.